# Pass variable as reference to jqueryui widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have widgetA with data structure - d. widgetA initializes widgetB and passes data to widgetB, like

```
$('<div>').widgetB({d:d});
```

But, when data in widgetA changes, in widgetB they dont, thats because when passing variables as options, jquery widget factory clones them.

How to pass reference pf variable to widget?

http://jsfiddle.net/sbNUh/

In this example widgetB does not change value and both times prints A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function like this

http://jsfiddle.net/sbNUh/1/

```
// widjet A
self.a = $('<div>').widgetB({ d: function() { return d; }}).appendTo(el);

....

// widjet B
$('#con').append('<div>'+this.options.d().a+'</div>');
```

This also signals more that you are actively retrieving the latest state

Answer (score 3):

Actually i found a trick to pass option by reference, if you reinitialize the widget the option is passed by reference (http://jsfiddle.net/sbNUh/8/).

Answer (score 1):

Change `d` to a function, in this way:

```
var private_var_d = "A";
function d(set){
    if(typeof set != "undefined") private_var_d = set;
    return private_var_d;
}
(self.a=$('<div>').widgetB({d:d}))
```

Whenever you want to get the variable, use: `this.options.d()`. When you want to change the variable, use `this.options.d("newvariable")`.

This method's effectiveness is based on how functions work: Functions can refer to variables which are defined in the same scope of definition. So, `function d` can always refer to `private_var_d`, because they're both defined in the same (anonymous) function.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sbNUh/2/**.

Answer (score 0):

You could try keeping a global variable that each widget uses.

Comment: There could be several widgetA widgets and each has his own data and own widgetB widgets.